# Form theme in Twig / Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

With Symfony and Twig, I have this form and this form theme :

`TrainingVersionType` *(this is collection)* :

```
class TrainingVersionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', null, [
                'attr' => [
                    'autofocus' => true,
                ],
                'label' => 'label.training_name',
                'ico' => 'pencil',
                'translation_domain' => 'administration',
            ])
            ->add('document', FineUploaderType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.attachments',
                'translation_domain' => 'administration',
                'limit' => 1,
                'acceptFiles' => [
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'image/png',
                ],
                'allowedExtensions' => [
                    'jpg',
                    'jpeg',
                    'png',
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }
```

**Form theme in my Twig file :**

```
{% block _training_versions_entry_name_widget %}
    <strong style="background: red; padding: 20px">
        Ok 1 :)
    </strong>
{% endblock %}

{% block _training_versions_entry_document_widget %}
    <strong style="background: blue; padding: 20px">
        Ok 2 :)
    </strong>
{% endblock %}
```

**Why I have "OK 1" and I don't have "OK 2" ?**

[image]

In my config.yml, I have this global form theme, But this is Widget for "FineUploaderType" :

```
{% block fineuploader_widget %}
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector card mb-3 bg-light">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector">
                <span class="btn btn-info">
                    {{ 'action.select'|trans({}, 'fineuploader') }}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ....
{% endblock %}
```

I want to add `div` in "document" entry in the form, for add help after FineUploader widget.

Can you help me ? :) Thanks

**Edit :**

`administration/training/new.html.twig` :

```
{% form_theme form 'administration/training/_form_theme.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ include('default/page/_new.html.twig', {
            form: form,
            btn_ico: 'plus',
            btn_value: 'action.training_new'|trans({}, 'administration'),
            back_label: 'action.training_back'|trans({}, 'administration'),
            back_path: path('administration_training')
        },
        with_context = false
    ) }}
{% endblock %}
```

`administration/training/_form_theme.html.twig` :

```
{% block _training_versions_entry_name_widget %}
    <strong style="background: red; padding: 20px">
        Ok 1 :)
    </strong>
{% endblock %}

{% block _training_versions_entry_document_widget %}
    <strong style="background: blue; padding: 20px">
        Ok 2 :)
    </strong>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you give the twig part where your form theme is applied to the form? I guess the fineuplaoder theme is overwriting your custom theme.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post but I don't understand why "fineuplaoder" theme is overwriting "document" theme